# TinyMCE: how to edit table width style tag on post

Tags: tinymce, width

I have a problem, and I haven't been able to solve it or find an answer for a few days now.

My theme (BusinessLite) for some reason has set table width in css to 100px!important.

This forces the TinyMCE made Tables to shrink as much as possible, thus making them useless.
TinyMCE by default converts the set width to inline style tag, but it is ignored since `!important` is present on the theme CSS. I have tried doing it manually, and i can confirm it fixes the issue, but i don't know of a way to make it automatic?

Does anyone know of a way to set TinyMCE to always add `!important` to the table width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `content_css` setting to load custom css and overwrite theme css.
You would need to issue the `!important` too to make it work.